# Adding elements to ArrayList<Type> and print them in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class called "NewType" where there is a string as attribute. In another class in the same package I created an `ArrayList<NewType>`.

How can I print the string parameters that I pass every time I create a NewType object (`new NewType("Hello")`)? Because using a for and printing just the object, it prints only the address of the new objects created. I know that I could just create an `ArrayList<String>`, but I need this also to understand how to work with the class types.

Here is what I tried:

```
Token j=new Token(part); //Token is th e "NewType" class type
tokenfinal.add(j); //tokenfinal is the ArrayList<Token> 

//CLASS TOKEN
public class Token   {
    public  String tok;
    
    public Token(String tok) { 
        this.tok=tok;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the following example:

```
public class Main {

    static class Person {
        private String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Person name: %s", this.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();


        personList.add(new Person("Test_Name"));
        personList.add(new Person("Name_Name"));

        personList.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Result:

```
Person name: Test_Name
Person name: Name_Name
```

You need to override toString() method in your Token class and customize it to return your field String tok or any other field you create

Comment: thanks a lot Svetlyo !! i dont know what i did not think about the  @Override before !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but you can do print value of the input string via override the toString method int the NewType class.

```
public class NewType {

    private String text;
    
    public NewType(String str) {
        text = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

By this, printing the class instance in print or println will call the overrided toString method.